# Get IP of Heroku dynos

Tags: linux, networking, heroku, heroku-cli

I have a Heroku app making some API calls to an external service. There are some issues and the service wants to know what IPs are making the calls.

A lot of the basic tools like `ifconfig`, `traceroute`, `netstat`, etc don't exist on the machines. Looks like they are running a very barebones version of Ubuntu 14.04.5.

I was able to use `heroku ps:exec -a <myapp>` to SSH into my app and use `ip addr` but there are some problems:

1) It appears that this only allows me to SSH into the web.1 dyno (and I am making my API calls through rest.1, rest.2, etc.)
2) These calls go through a router on Heroku's side.

How can I get the IPs of all dyno instances and/or the router?

Comment: How can this be downvoted??? It's as explicit as could possibly be and it follows all of the guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I agree, this is a valid question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Get the list of dynos with the `heroku ps -a <app>` command.

You actually can ssh into individual dyno instances with `heroku ps:exec -a <app> -d <dyno_instance> --ssh`.

Get the individual dyno IP with the `ip` command e.g. `ip addr | grep "global eth0" | awk '{ print $2 }'`.

Get the router IP with `curl 'https://api.ipify.org'`. http://httpbin.org/ip is also good.

You could use `expect` to programmatically retrieve the IPs from every dyno by running the Heroku SSH command, waiting for the prompt, running the IP command(s), logging out, then repeating for each dyno instance.

Comment: Using this I'm getting a private IP in the form of `172.17...`

Answer (score 6):

According to the [docs](https://kb.heroku.com/i-need-to-whitelist-heroku-dynos-what-are-ip-address-ranges-in-use-at-heroku), Heroku Dynos can be any IP from an AWS Region. Having a dedicated/static IP for your Dynos is part of their [enterprise offering](https://www.heroku.com/private-spaces).

However, you can have a dedicated/static IP by adding an add-on (e.g. [Fixie](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/fixie), [Proximo](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/proximo) or [one of these add-ons](https://elements.heroku.com/search/addons?q=static%20ip))

Also, you can have the Dynos make a GET request to https://httpbin.org/ip and it will respond with the Dynos public IP (more ideas in the comments section below).

Comment: They can certainly change over time, but at a given moment they must have an IP.

Comment: They might change at a faster rate than you can manage, but here is a way to expose their public/internet facing IP. Create a RequestBin from https://requestb.in and have the Dynos make request to it and refresh the page to see all requests made to that unique https://requestb.in/XXXXXX url .

Comment: Or even make a `GET` request to `https://httpbin.org/ip` and it will return the Dynos public IP for you.