# Expect script to wait for Heroku ssh prompt

Tags: heroku, expect, heroku-cli

I want to use an `expect` script to run an SSH command on Heroku dynos (for example: [Get IP of Heroku dynos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46186991/get-ip-of-heroku-dynos/46188051#46188051))

The exact output when logging into the dyno is:

```
 ▸    heroku-cli: update available from 6.12.9 to 6.14.21-d83c94b
Establishing credentials... done
Connecting to <dyno> on ⬢ <app>...
~ $
```

I'm sure the first line would be gone after updating. It takes several seconds for this authentication/login to actually occur.

A simple expect script could go like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn "./ssh_into_heroku"
expect "xxxx"
send "my_command"
```

I've tried `expect "~ $" { send "my_cmd" }` and `expect "~ $ " { send "my_cmd" }` but neither are working and I have no idea how to debug this.

What would go in the "expect" portion to make this work?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's very explicit and it follows everything here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're waiting for the prompt that ends with a space, a dollar sign and (I'm guessing) another space. You would use this:

```
set prompt_regex { \$ $}
expect -re $prompt_regex
```